# .NET Entity Framework - duplicate entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

***Usefull Context***

I currently have two entities that look as below.

MovieSerie

```
    public class MovieSerie
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid MovieSerieId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

Movie

```
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid MovieId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual MovieSerie MovieSerie { get; set; }
    }
```

I have removed some properties that were unused so far so the example is a bit more readable.

These entities have a one-to-many relationship because a MovieSerie contains multiple movies but a movie can only belong to one MovieSerie.

***The problem***

When I am trying to make a new movie from Postman by providing an EXISTING MovieSerie, I am getting an exception. The exception looks as below.

> Duplicate entry '\xA9\xCE\x0E\x1E\x9A\xAE\xA2G\x91<\xE6\xE3-\x88C\xE9' for key 'movieseries.PRIMARY'

So I figured out that it is trying to make a new MovieSerie when I am providing a MovieSerie object. The raw JSON from the request that I am trying to send from Postman looks like below.

```
{
    "MovieId" : "6aa8c134-689c-45e2-bf60-cd0eb5473cc2",
    "Title" : "TestMovie",
    "MovieSerie" : {
        "movieSerieId": "1e0ecea9-ae9a-47a2-913c-e6e32d8843e9",
        "title": "Harry Potter",
        "description": "This contains the Harry Potter serie"
    }
}
```

The POST method to save the movie is shown below.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> PostMovie(Movie movie)
        {
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("No movie object provided");
            }

            else if (movie.MovieSerie != null)
            {
                if (!_validator.MovieSerieExists(movie.MovieSerie.MovieSerieId))
                {
                    return BadRequest("The movie serie does not exists in the database");
                }
            }

            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetMovie", new { id = movie.MovieId }, movie);
        }
```

Could someone give me any insight into what I am doing wrong? Why is it trying to make a new entity while it already exists? What should I change to get the wished behavior?

I tried to provide all information required, however, let me know if I missed something.

**EDIT ADDED DBCONTEXT**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<MovieSerie>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(movieSerie => movieSerie.MovieSerieId);
                entity.Property(movieSerie => movieSerie.Title).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(movieSerie => movieSerie.Description).IsRequired();
                entity.HasMany(ms => ms.Movies)
                .WithOne(m => m.MovieSerie);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(movie => movie.MovieId);
                entity.Property(movie => movie.Title).IsRequired();
                entity.HasOne(m => m.MovieSerie)
                .WithMany(s => s.Movies);
            });
```

Comment: You have to check to see if the moving is already in the database before you try to add.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when passing entities between server and client in ASP.Net. When your DbContext is lifetime scoped to a request, the entities are loaded by a DbContext and passed to the view, but then what you pass back on the Post call is a JSON object that is deserialized into an entity class definition. On *this* request, neither the Movie or it's associated related entities are tracked by the DbContext.

When you tell the Post's DbContext to Add the movie, any child entities on that movie will be treated as ***new*** entities as well, resulting in duplicate records.

How to avoid this:

Option 1: Use ViewModels to avoid confusing data coming from views with entities. (Data state) This is always my recommended option. This avoids confusion about what objects you are dealing with, and also means you can reduce the amount of data being sent over the wire. As entities get larger, sending entities back and forth means larger payloads for fields your view doesn't need. ViewModels can be populated to serve just the fields that the view will interact with. Automapper can help largely with turning entity graphs into ViewModels with it's `ProjectTo` method.

So if we had a view for creating a Movie (Movie/Create) and that view listed a the movie series to choose from, it might search/fetch series:

```
[Serializable]
public class MovieSeriesSummaryViewModel
{
    public Guid MovieSeriesId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then when the controller goes to search/retrieve those series to choose from:

```
var series = _context.MovieSeries
      // .Where(x => [search criteria...])
      .ProjectTo<MovieSeriesSummaryViewModel>(config)
      .ToList();
```

or

```
var series = _context.MovieSeries
      // .Where(x => [search criteria...])
      .Select( x = > new MovieSeriesSummaryViewModel
      {
          MovieSeriesId = x.MovieSeriesId,
          Name = x.Name
      }).ToList();
```

a PostMovie action accepts a PostMovieViewModel:

```
[Serializable]
public class PostMovieViewModel
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public Guid? MovieSeriesId { get; set; }
    // ... 
}
```

The create movie view model only needs to pass the series ID (if applicable) and the required fields to create a new movie. From there we associate the series from the DbContext when creating our new Movie:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<PostMovieViewModel>> PostMovie(PostMovieViewModel movieVM)
{
    var movieSeries = movieVM.MovieSeriesId.HasValue 
        ? _context.MovieSeries.Single(x => x.MovieSeriesId == movieVM.MovieSeriesId.Value)
        : null;
    var movie = new Movie
    {
        Name = movieVM.Name,
        MovieSeries = movieSeries
    };
    _context.Movies.Add(movie);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The key point here is that we fetch the existing series from the Context to associate to the new movie. Fetching entities by ID is quite fast and serves as a meaningful validation that the data we passed in is complete.

Option 2: Re-associate all references. The underlying problem with passing deserialize objects and treating them as entities is that the DbContext isn't tracking them. There are 2 ways you can fix this, either tell the DbContext to track them, or replace the references with tracked objects.

2a - Replacing references

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> PostMovie(Movie movie)
{
     if (movie.MovieSeries != null)
     {
         var existingMovieSeries = _context.MovieSeries
             .Single(x => MovieSeriesId == movie.MovieSeries.MovieSeriesId);
         movie.MovieSeries = existingMovieSeries; // Replace the reference.
     }
     _context.Movies.Add(movie);
     await _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This still potentially means going to the DB for all references, and forgetting to will result in silent duplication issues.

2b - Track related entities. This one I saved for last as it can seem simple, but can trip you up...

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> PostMovie(Movie movie)
{
     if (movie.MovieSeries != null)
         _context.Attach(movie.MovieSeries);

     _context.Movies.Add(movie);
     await _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

That looks simple, and would work most of the time, but *if* the DbContext is already tracking that movie series for any reason, the Attach method will fail. This is an error that could appear intermittently at runtime depending on the particular actions/data combinations. (I.e. updating 2 movies /w same series or conditionally calling a method that loads that series) The proper check would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> PostMovie(Movie movie)
{
     if (movie.MovieSeries != null)
     {   
         var existingMovieSeries = _context.MovieSeries.Local
             .SingleOrDefault(x => x.MovieSeriesId == movie.MovieSeries.MovieSeriesId);
         if (existingMovieSeries == null)
             _context.Attach(movie.MovieSeries);
         else
             movie.MovieSeries = existingMovieSeries;
     }
     _context.Movies.Add(movie);
     await _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Checking `MovieSeries.Local` checks to see if the DbContext is tracking the series. (without hitting the DB) If not, we can attach it. If it is, we need to replace the reference.  This can be a lot of boiler plate code to put in for every reference on a new object. When attaching entities coming from a view, it is also important *not* to ever set the entity state for that entity to `Modified` without first verifying the data is valid. (Which would require loading the entity first anyway) Doing so could allow users to alter data in ways you don't intend as setting an entity to `Modified` will update *all* fields on that entity. (Where loading an entity and then copying across values means only those values you change will be updated)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing the whole movie serie object. This is not something you should do. The idea of relational databases is to, as the name suggest, relate tables. This relationships are done using keys (foreign keys).
In your particular case, you need to define a foreign key column in your Movie table, to relate it to MovieSeries, as follows:

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MovieId { get; set; }
    public int MovieSerieId {get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MovieSerieID")]
    public virtual MovieSerie MovieSerie { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, im specifying that the MovieSerieID attribute is a foreign key. The virtual MovieSerie attribute is used by EF to get all the details of your foreign key.

Now, you can create your movie passing only the MovieSerieid, as follows:

```
{
    "MovieId" : "6aa8c134-689c-45e2-bf60-cd0eb5473cc2",
    "Title" : "TestMovie",
    "MovieSerieId": "1e0ecea9-ae9a-47a2-913c-e6e32d8843e9"
}
```

Comment: Hello Ronny. Thanks for your answer. That sounds good, I thought I could just provide the whole object. I am going to test it out soon and then I will mark your comment as answer.

Comment: I just tested it out and I have a question about this. Does this mean that I also have to change the relationship in the DatabaseContext? Because now I can send the request, it says 200(ok) and it made the Movie entity. Although the MovieSerie object is null.

Comment: Does your MovieSerieId property exists in your model and in your database ?
By default, entity framework should have created a MovieSerie_Id that is not present in your model and uses it to load your property MovieSerie.
Did you create a migration after changing your model ?

Comment: Please add the DatabaseContext code to your initial question. As @Béranger says, you have to make sure that the MovieSerieId property exists in your db.

Comment: @RonnyCordova  I have just added the DB Context. Besides that, the MovieSerieId column exists in my Movie table. It is a foreign key.